# Need help making constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I need help with my c++ code.
I need to make constructor and object for class Posao in this code. But when I make constructor it shows me error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Radnik
{
private:
    string ime;
    string prezime;
    int koeficijentSS;
    bool zaposlen;
public:
    Radnik(string, string, int, bool);
    string getIme();
    string getPrezime();
    int getKoeficijent();
    bool getStatus();
    void promeniIme(string);
    void promeniPrezime(string);
    void promeniKoeficijent(int);
    void promeniStatus(bool);
};
class Posao: public Radnik
{
private:
    Radnik radnik1;
    Radnik radnik2;
public:
    void PromeniRadnik1(Radnik);
    void PromeniRadnik2(Radnik);
};
Radnik::Radnik(string a, string b, int c, bool d)
{
    ime = a;
    prezime = b;
    koeficijentSS = c;
    zaposlen = d;
}
string Radnik::getIme()
{
    return ime;
}
string Radnik::getPrezime()
{
    return prezime;
}
int Radnik::getKoeficijent()
{
    return koeficijentSS;
}
bool Radnik::getStatus()
{
    return zaposlen;
}
void Radnik::promeniIme(string e)
{
    ime = e;
}
void Radnik::promeniPrezime(string f)
{
    prezime = f;
}
void Radnik::promeniKoeficijent(int g)
{
    koeficijentSS = g;
}
void Radnik::promeniStatus(bool h)
{
    zaposlen = h;
}
void Posao::PromeniRadnik1(Radnik x)
{
    radnik1.promeniIme(x.getIme());
    radnik1.promeniPrezime(x.getPrezime());
    radnik1.promeniKoeficijent(x.getKoeficijent());
    radnik1.promeniStatus(x.getStatus());
}
void Posao::PromeniRadnik2(Radnik y)
{
    radnik2.promeniIme(y.getIme());
    radnik2.promeniPrezime(y.getPrezime());
    radnik2.promeniKoeficijent(y.getKoeficijent());
    radnik2.promeniStatus(y.getStatus());
}
int main()
{
    Radnik radnikPrvi("djuro", "djuric", false, 3);
    Radnik radnikDrugi("momcilo", "sportista", true, 2);
    Radnik radnikTreci("gavrilo", "burek", false, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Can you write me how to make constructor with parameters and object for class Posao.

I need this for school project. Hope you can find way to fix it. Thanks

Thanks in advance,
BlackAdder

Comment: `Radnik` lacks a default constructor, so it appears you are looking for how to use a [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Answer (score 3):

As Posao inherits from Radnik, Posao's constructor will call Radnik's constructor.
As user4581301 said, Radnik has no default constructor, which is the only constructor the compiler can call for you, so you must call it explicitely using [Initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

But, do you really want Posao inherit from Radnik? Seems that you want Posao use Radnik, but don't be a Radnik subclass...

Comment: A good point. I don't know what `Posao` and `Radnik` mean so I didn't even consider whether or not there is a valid is-a relationship.

Comment: @user4581301 Posao means work and Radnik is an employee - worker. Radnik has all the employees data - like first (ime) and last name (prezime), but also the bool "zaposlen" which is true if employed and false otherwise. Indeed, the current structure doesn't seem very reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you write me how to make constructor with parameters and object
>   for class Posao.

First you need a default constructor in class `Radnik`, which will becalled when you pass parameters to the constructor of class `Posao`.
This can be done by simply

```
Radnik() = default;
```

Constructor of class `Posao` with parameters will look like this.

```
Posao(std::string a1, std::string b1, int c1, bool d1,
      std::string a2, std::string b2, int c2, bool d2)
    :radnik1(a1, b1, c1, d1),
     radnik2(a2, b2, c2, d2)
    {}
```

Constructor of class `Posao` with objects of  `Radnik` will look like this.

```
Posao(Radnik r1, Radnik r2)
        :radnik1(r1), radnik2(r2)
        {}
```

Once you have both, in the `main()`, you can create instance of class `Posao` like follows:

```
int main()
{
    //carefull while passing para:
    //          Radnik(string a, string b, int c, bool d)
    Radnik radnikPrvi("djuro", "djuric", 3, false);
    Radnik radnikDrugi("momcilo", "sportista", 2, true );

    // constructor with parameters
    Posao obj_parameters("ime1", "prezime1", 1, true,
                         "ime2", "prezime2", 2, false);
    // constructor with Radnik objects object
    Posao obj_objets(radnikPrvi, radnikDrugi);
    return 0;
}
```

It is always a good practice to use [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) in the constructor, rather than creating and assigning. Then you must also be careful that initializer list need the parameters in the order how you declared in the private.

In your `main()`, you have misplaced `bool` and `int` parameters.

```
                                         |||||  |
    Radnik radnikPrvi("djuro", "djuric", false, 3);
    Radnik radnikDrugi("momcilo", "sportista", true, 2);
    Radnik radnikTreci("gavrilo", "burek", false, 1);
```